# txt file to string to array into mysqli db with php

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

UPDATED2

I have a txt file(output.txt) generated that looks like this, but there are varying numbers of arrays of doorGroups

```
{"DGGroups"[{"DoorGroupID":"1","DoorGroupName":"Default","DoorGroupStatus":"Lock"}{"DoorGroupID":"2","DoorGroupName":"Group 1","DoorGroupStatus":"Unlock"}{"DoorGroupID":"3","DoorGroupName":"Group 2","DoorGroupStatus":"Lock"{"DoorGroupID":"4","DoorGroupName":"Group 3","DoorGroupStatus":"Unlock"}{"DoorGroupID":"5","DoorGroupName":"Group 4","DoorGroupStatus":"Lock"}]}
```

I need to be able to rip through the file and insert the values into the mysqli db that has corresponding columns

```
    id  doorGroupID     doorGroupName   doorGroupStatus
```

This is the non working code i have at the moment - I have tried many variations. I cut out some things on the string to make it better to work with. Calling jsondecode still returns NULL. I have it operating on a button press. Any direction will be appreciated.

```
//Forms posted
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
 //read the  file contents
$data = file_get_contents('output.txt');
var_dump($data);
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";

$data = substr($data, 13, strlen($data) - 17); // remove outer ( and )
$data = str_replace('"', "", $data); 
$data = str_replace('{', "", $data); 
$data = str_replace('}', "|", $data);
var_dump($data);

echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";


$output = json_decode($data, true);
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($output); 


$ret = array_map (
  function ($_) {return explode (',', $_);},
  explode ('|', $data)
);

print_r ($ret);





    //insert into mysql table
    $sql = "INSERT INTO doorGroups(doorGroupID, doorGroupName, doorGroupStatus)
    VALUES('$DoorGroupID', '$DoorGroupName', '$DoorGroupStatus')";


   if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "<h3>updated successfully</h3>";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();

}

?>


<div class='container' >
<form  method='post'>

<div class='container'>  
      <form class='form-horizontal'>
        <div class='form-group'>  
        </div>
      </form>


        <button type='submit' name='submit' class='btn btn-primary center-block'>Do It</button>
      </div>  
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
</head>
</html>
```

the file outputs to this

```
    string(371) "{"DGGroups"[{"DoorGroupID":"1","DoorGroupName":"Default","DoorGroupStatus":"Lock"}{"DoorGroupID":"2","DoorGroupName":"Group 1","DoorGroupStatus":"Unlock"}{"DoorGroupID":"3","DoorGroupName":"Group 2","DoorGroupStatus":"Lock"}{"DoorGroupID":"4","DoorGroupName":"Group 3","DoorGroupStatus":"Unlock"}{"DoorGroupID":"5","DoorGroupName":"Group 4","DoorGroupStatus":"unLock"}]} "

string(290) "DoorGroupID:1,DoorGroupName:Default,DoorGroupStatus:Lock|DoorGroupID:2,DoorGroupName:Group 1,DoorGroupStatus:Unlock|DoorGroupID:3,DoorGroupName:Group 2,DoorGroupStatus:Lock|DoorGroupID:4,DoorGroupName:Group 3,DoorGroupStatus:Unlock|DoorGroupID:5,DoorGroupName:Group 4,DoorGroupStatus:unLock"

NULL
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => DoorGroupID:1
            [1] => DoorGroupName:Default
            [2] => DoorGroupStatus:Lock
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => DoorGroupID:2
            [1] => DoorGroupName:Group 1
            [2] => DoorGroupStatus:Unlock
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => DoorGroupID:3
            [1] => DoorGroupName:Group 2
            [2] => DoorGroupStatus:Lock
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => DoorGroupID:4
            [1] => DoorGroupName:Group 3
            [2] => DoorGroupStatus:Unlock
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => DoorGroupID:5
            [1] => DoorGroupName:Group 4
            [2] => DoorGroupStatus:unLock
        )

)
updated successfully
```

So basically now the hangup is i can get the string to explode to the right groups but i cant access the value pairs.  It is a group of value pair groups.  How do i break it down so that i have the info in the same groups and access to the corresponding information?

Comment: What does `var_dump ($jsondata);` return?

Comment: EDITED!!  removed $jsondata and its now just data

Comment: Is that supposed to be json? If so, it's got syntax errors. `}{` is not valid... if it is suppsoed to be json, then you need to fix whatever's generating that, and then you can simply `json_decode()` it and get an ACTUAL array/object structure, eliminating all of this string fiddling you're doing.

Comment: i agree but the string is generated from a server in this format - not under my control -

Comment: Most common type of data transfer languages are xml and json. It looks like json. You should try json_decode ()

Comment: if i add var_dump(json_decode($data, true)); i get NULL

Comment: i changed the question around to show the updated progress  - still cant get json_decode to give a response other than null

Comment: Possibly using the explode () function would allow you to do this. For example: `explode(',', $data);` then you can do another one exploding the ':'.

Comment: yeah i tried explode and it is on the right track i believe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bastardized version of JSON, but I think it can be beaten into submission with regular expressions. (Yes, I know, now I have two problems...)

As well, you absolutely do not want to be dumping external data into your database without safeguards. You may think it's trustworthy because it comes from another server in your organization, but it's not. Prepared statements give you protection and also greatly reduce the overhead needed to get this stuff into the database.

```
<?php
#set up the database stuff
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$sql = "INSERT INTO doorGroups(doorGroupID, doorGroupName, doorGroupStatus)
VALUES(?,?,?)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

# the data; one missing } was added from the question
$data = '{"DGGroups"[{"DoorGroupID":"1","DoorGroupName":"Default","DoorGroupStatus":"Lock"}{"DoorGroupID":"2","DoorGroupName":"Group 1","DoorGroupStatus":"Unlock"}{"DoorGroupID":"3","DoorGroupName":"Group 2","DoorGroupStatus":"Lock"}{"DoorGroupID":"4","DoorGroupName":"Group 3","DoorGroupStatus":"Unlock"}{"DoorGroupID":"5","DoorGroupName":"Group 4","DoorGroupStatus":"Lock"}]}';
# grab the members of DGGroups
preg_match('/"DGGroups"\[({.*?}+)\]/', $data, $matches);
# split the members into individual elements
$doorgroups = explode("{", $matches[1]);
# get rid of the empty element at the beginning
array_shift($doorgroups);
# now work with each
foreach ($doorgroups as $dg) {
    # decode it, don't forget preg_split stripped off the separator
    $dg = json_decode("{" . $dg);
    # bind the variables to the statement
    $stmt->bind_param("iss", $dg->DoorGroupID, $dg->DoorGroupName, $dg->DoorGroupStatus);
    # execute it
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Of course you'll want to do some error checking on the results of `mysqli::prepare()`, `preg_match()`, `json_decode()`, etc.

Comment: very nice - thanks for cleaning up my mess.  im not good with PDO yet  - would i UPDATE in the same basic way - i guess the pointers in the stmt binding could still be used? Say to UPDATE doorGroupStatus based on doorGroupID

Comment: This isn't PDO, though I'd suggest using PDO over MySQLi. You can prepare any kind of query, placeholders can be used in the `WHERE` clause as well, just don't forget to keep track of the order of the parameters.

Comment: oh ok thanks  - that shows how much i need to learn - so something like this or i guess im not sure what you mean by keeping track of the parameters  $sql = "UPDATE  doorGroups SET doorGroupStatus=?, doorGroupName=? WHERE doorGroupID=?";

Comment: Yes, just make sure that everything is in the proper order when you do `$stmt->bind_param()`.

Comment: when i set    $stmt->bind_param("iss", $dg->DoorGroupName, $dg->DoorGroupStatus, $dg->DoorGroupID);  and   $sql = "UPDATE  doorGroups SET doorGroupName=?, doorGroupStatus=?  WHERE doorGroupID=?";  the doorGroupName field fills with all zeros.  Does this look correct? Got it tThanks

Comment: First parameter needs to change also. [Read the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) before you use this function in production!